# Use signals stored in a python dict

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

I would like to dynamically create then manipulate lots of widgets. My idea is to store widgets in a dict (mywidgets) and to trigger them with signals stored in another dict (mysignals). Both dict shared same keys defined in a list (names), dicts are initialized with for loops.

When I connect signals to slots, I'm currently facing an AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'.

I have tried to disable signal/slot connections: the GUI looks good, QLineEdit are well stored in mywidgets. Types of mysignals items are correct: class 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal'.

Can you, please, explain me where the issue come from ?
Thanks.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal

class App(QWidget):

    names = ["foo","bar"]
    mysignals = {}    # Store several signals in a dict
    for name in names:
        mysignals[name] = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create Widgets
        self.btn_go = QPushButton("Go")     #Simple push button
        self.mywidgets = {}                   #Store several QLineEdit in a dict
        for name in self.names:
            self.mywidgets[name] = QLineEdit()

        # Connect signals
        self.btn_go.clicked.connect(self.on_click)                  #Connect push button
        for name in self.names:
            print(type(self.mysignals[name]))
            self.mysignals[name].connect(self.mywidgets[name].setText)  #Connect several signals

        # Configure layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_go)
        for name in self.names:
            layout.addWidget(self.mywidgets[name])
        self.setLayout(layout) 

        # Show widget
        self.show()


    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        data = {"foo":"Python3","bar":"PyQt5"}
        for key,value in data.items():
            self.mysignals[key].emit(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The expected result is to display respectivelly Python3 and PyQt5 in mywidgets["foo"] and mywidgets["bar"] QLineEdit widgets when push button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#unbound-and-bound-signals) point out:

> A signal (specifically an unbound signal) is a class attribute. When a
>   signal is referenced as an attribute of an instance of the class then
>   PyQt5 automatically binds the instance to the signal in order to
>   create a bound signal. This is the same mechanism that Python itself
>   uses to create bound methods from class functions.

A signal is declared as an attribute of the class but when referenced through self a bind is made with the object, that is, the declared signal is different from the instantiated signal:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Foo(QtCore.QObject):
    fooSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    print("declared:", fooSignal)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        print("instantiated:", self.fooSignal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Foo()
```

Output:

```
declared: <unbound PYQT_SIGNAL )>
instantiated: <bound PYQT_SIGNAL fooSignal of Foo object at 0x7f4beb998288>
```

That is the reason for the error you get, so if you want to use the signals you must obtain it using the object so we can inspect the attributes and get the signals:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    foo = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    bar = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fill_signals()
        self.names = ["foo", "bar"]

        self.btn_go = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Go")
        self.mywidgets = {}
        for name in self.names:
            self.mywidgets[name] = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            signal = self.mysignals.get(name)
            if signal is not None:
                signal.connect(self.mywidgets[name].setText)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_go)
        for name in self.names:
            layout.addWidget(self.mywidgets[name])

        self.btn_go.clicked.connect(self.testing)

    def fill_signals(self):
        self.mysignals = dict()
        for p in dir(self):
            attr = getattr(self, p)
            if isinstance(attr, QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal):
                self.mysignals[p] = attr

    def testing(self):
        self.foo.emit("foo")
        self.bar.emit("bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. I will dig bound and unbound methods.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think you have complicated the algorithm to obtain the expected result. Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, names):
        super().__init__()

        self.names = names
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create Widgets
        self.btn_go = QPushButton("Go")            # Simple push button
        self.btn_go.clicked.connect(self.on_click) # Connect push button
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_go)

        self.mywidgets = {}                        # Store several QLineEdit in a dict
        for name in self.names:
            self.mywidgets[name] = QLineEdit()    
            layout.addWidget(self.mywidgets[name])

        self.setLayout(layout) 

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        data = {"foo":"Python3", "bar":"PyQt5"}
        for key, value in data.items():
            self.mywidgets[key].setText(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    names = ["foo", "bar"]
    ex = App(names)

    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]